# Skipping sound track (pygame.mixer.music)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, mixer

I  am making a snake game with pygame and I want to know something about `pygame.mixer.music()`.

Code:

```
snakebodypos.insert(0, list(snakepos))
if snakepos[0] == foodpos[0] and snakepos[1] == foodpos[1]:
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(eatsound)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(1, 0.0)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(main)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
    foodspawn = False
    score += 1
```

So, when I stop and the eatsound is supposed to play, it just skips it and plays the stopped sound again.

**KEEP IN MIND!**
When I use pause and unpause, it doesn't unpause again. I don't know why so I use the stop. If you know why that happens, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you want to stop the background music while playing the `eatsound`?

Your code does not work because after you load and play `eatsound`, you immediatly load `main` again, so `eatsound` has no time to play.

---

Usually, you use `pygame.mixer.music` to play background music, and for sound effects, you use [`pygame.mixer.Sound`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound), so your code should look like this:

```
# load the Sound once at the beginning
eatsound_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(eatsound)

...

snakebodypos.insert(0, list(snakepos))
if snakepos[0] == foodpos[0] and snakepos[1] == foodpos[1]:
    # play the eat sound. don't touch the background music
    eatsound_sound.play() 
    foodspawn = False
    score += 1
```